# How to do prediction in keras without labels

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I have image path in data frame and I want to predict the label of each.
What I do is create a data generator as follow

```
test_generator=data_gen.flow_from_dataframe(test_df,directory='',
                                                    target_size=(img_shape,img_shape),
                                                    x_col="image",
                                                    y_col='label',
                                                    class_mode='binary',
                                                    shuffle=False,
                                                    batch_size=batch_size)
pred=model.predict(test_df)
```

At this stage, I don't have  labels so I create a label column of zeros
It throws error
`ValueError: If class_mode="binary" there must be 2 classes. Found 1 classes.`

I change `class_mode` to `raw`, now I got error as
`ValueError: Input 0 is incompatible with layer model: expected shape=(None, 224, 224, 3), found shape=(None, 2)`

Then I try commenting out the `y_col` and `class_mode` line
I got error `KeyError: 'class'`.
So what should I do?

Comment: I'd have a hard time reproducing the problem given your question, but the documentation suggests setting `class_mode = None`

Comment: i had already tried, but it did not worked

Comment: what is failing? creating the generator, or predicting? Because you aren't even using the generator when you call `model.predict(test_df)`

Comment: yes, this is the issue. my bad, thanks